# Make object move out from origin in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am rather new to three.js, and I am creating a cube that should pop. However, I cannot find a way to make an edge piece on the cube move away from the origin. How can I do this? The cube code can be found at https://github.com/molarmanful/DayanZhanchi in the gh-pages branch.

Comment: There is not a `ERNO.Cube` object in the Three.JS source. I can answer you question for a BoxGeometry but it doesn't seem you are using the standard Three.JS library.

Comment: Nope. ERNO.Cube is a plugin from Three.JS. the code is minified in cuber.min.js